# xcodebuild linker failing when custom output directory provided

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I have a problem using `xcodebuild` to build the iOS app to custom directory.

Everything works well if I am building using command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyAppScheme -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

...but I would like the `.app` and `.dSYM` files to be saved in a specific directory (`./build` for example). So, I tried adding:

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=./build
```

or

```
OBJROOT=./build SYMROOT=./build
```

as a `xcodebuild` parameters. Then I've got this error (output comes from `xctool` as it's more readable, but the same error occurs when using `xcodebuild`):

> ✗ Link MyApp
>
> (...)
>
> ld: library not found for -lPods-MyApp-SomePodName
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

As I am using Cocoapods, my workspace contains app's project and "Pods" project. I tried using `xcodebuild` on several other projects that uses Cocoapods and I am always getting this error (`SomePodName` differs depending on project's dependencies) when trying to provide custom output directory. Please note, that it works without an issue when `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`, `OBJROOT` and `SYMROOT` parameters are skipped.

I wonder if anything changed recently, because I am pretty sure that I was able to build to custom directory using `xcodebuild` in the past. Currently, Travis-CI is still able to do it without an issue, but I have no luck when trying on my local machines.

Perhaps providing `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`, `OBJROOT` or `SYMROOT` is not the perfect way for specifying custom output directory. I am not sure if the problem is connected directly to Cocoapods, but the errors are always connected with some pod library.

Any hints will be appreciated.

My environment:

- OS X 10.10.3
- Xcode 6.3
- xctool 0.2.3
- cocoapods 0.36.3

---

### Update: Problem solved

It looks like `xcodebuild` requires absolute path for `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`, `OBJROOT` and `SYMROOT` parameters.

Providing absolute path solved the problem:

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/me/Dev/MyApp/build
```

Comment: If you are specifying a build directory other than the default then try using an absolute path instead `/Users/Username/build/`. It's unclear if the directory you want to save to is within the project root.

Comment: @l'L'l - OMG, I can't believe I didn't think about it. Thanks! It solved my problem.

Comment: No worries :) The default `build` directory in your project can usually be specified with `$(PROJECT_DIR)/build` for `OBJROOT` and `SYMROOT`, so you could possibly try changing that to something like `$(PROJECT_DIR)/custom_build` too (if you wanted the directory to remain within the project folders)

Comment: I will only need that when building from command line. Btw. perhaps you can advice which is better `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` or `OBJROOT + SYMROOT` when I just need `.app`, `.a` and `.dSYM` files in separate directory?